# Changing URL on AngularJS without transitioning state for a particular link, but keeping the URL in the link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser-history, angular-ui-router

I have a link which has two actions. When I click on it, it opens a modal box via "ng-click", but it also transitions state via its "ng-href".

The modal box opening is intended. The state transition is not. However I need the URL in that state transition to persist.

When I try to use $locationChangeStart to prevent the state change, it also prevents the URL from changing. This is not preferable. I've also researched a bit, and found potential solutions in "reloadOnSearch". However it doesn't possible to point to a particular link. Not all of the links on the page do this, the other links are all normal links. Furthermore I don't know how to use reloadOnSearch with ui-router.

The feature I'm trying to implement is similar to Pinterest's overlay of items. When you click on the item, they open up a modal box and change the URL, but the underlying page doesn't change. This allows the end user to copy the URL and share it with their friends, and when they access it, it will actually go directly the item page and not the overlay.

I'm currently using ui-router if that makes anything easier.

Hopefully somebody has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try angular ui bootstrap modal for better integration with angularJS.
Take a look at an example in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
Or you may open a modal via data-target="#abc" instead of href="#abc"